How can I get the error codes in github-actions shell when a docker run command fails while piping the output to file and CLI
I'm trying to capture both the output and the error status of a Docker command in GitHub Actions. Even when the command inside Docker fails, I'm getting a successful exit code. Here's my current workflow:
name: Test Docker Command

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run test
        run: |
          docker run tensorpod/pymimic3:latest \
            bash -ic "pytest tests/test_metrics" 2>&1 | tee output.txt
          
          echo "Pipe status: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
          echo "Exit status: $?"
          
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "The command failed."
            exit 1
          fi

Both ${PIPESTATUS[0]} and $? are returning 0 (success) even when the pytest command inside Docker fails. I know GitHub Actions uses bash with set -eo pipefail by default, but it's still not capturing the failure.
Question:
How can I correctly capture and handle the exit status of the Docker command while still piping its output to both a file and the console?
Additional Info:
I need to capture both stdout and stderr (2>&1)
I need to see the output in real-time in the GitHub Actions log
I need to save the output to a file
I need the step to fail if the command inside Docker fails
Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Try to put redirections in double-quotes: bash -ic "pytest tests/test_metrics 2>&1  | tee output.txt"

In fact, this was the solution I have been looking for. God bless you.


How can I correctly capture and handle the exit status of the Docker command while still piping its output to both a file and the console?

The potential issue probably is that, when using a pipe (|) to send the output of one command to another, only the exit code of the last command in the pipeline is captured by $?, not the exit code of the original Docker command.
docker run tensorpod/pymimic3:latest \
        bash -ic "pytest tests/test_metrics" 2>&1 | tee output.txt

What you can try to capture the correct exit code of the Docker command while still piping its output to both a file and the console
name: Test Docker Command

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run test
        run: |
          docker_output=$(docker run tensorpod/pymimic3:latest \
              bash -ic "pytest tests/test_metrics" 2>&1)

          docker_exit_code=$?
          echo "$docker_output" | tee output.txt
      
          echo "Pipe status: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
          echo "Exit status: $docker_exit_code"

          if [ $docker_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "The command inside Docker failed."
            exit 1
          fi

